# Origen de la acepción peyorativa de "chaleco" en Andalucía

Tags: definiciones, españa, sustantivos, lenguaje-peyorativo

Es el año 2019. En toda España se define *[jersey](https://dle.rae.es/?id=MQr0hNQ)* como "prenda de vestir de punto, cerrada y **con mangas**, que cubre desde el cuello hasta la cintura" y *[chaleco](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8UQukGi)* como "prenda de vestir **sin mangas**, que cubre el tronco hasta la cintura". ¿En toda? ¡No! Una pequeña aldea poblada por irreductibles sevillanos resiste, todavía y siempre, a la Academia. Y la vida no es fácil para las provincias aledañas que se quieren comunicar con sus habitantes...

Efectivamente, en Sevilla un *chaleco* es un *jersey* o, como dicen en Fititu:

> **[Chaleco](http://fititu.es/?s=chaleco)**
>   Dícese del jersey de pico, suéter o sucedáneo de manga larga que no abriga mucho.

Pero, ¡oh, sorpresa!, me hallaba yo buscando definiciones ante la enésima discusión al respecto producida a mi alrededor, cuando descubro que resulta que aquí en Sevilla (y en el resto de Andalucía) la voz *chaleco* tiene además una acepción que no conocía:

> 3. m. *And.* Mujer despreciable y sin atractivos. U. t. c. adj.

Esta acepción, introducida en el DLE en 1970 sin marca alguna de uso regional, me sorprende porque jamás había oído algo así. Lo malo es que dado lo común de la palabra no localizo casos en el CORDE o en el CREA con ejemplos de su uso con esta acepción.

Pregunto pues, ¿qué ejemplos se pueden encontrar de su uso con este significado? ¿Desde cuándo se usa así? ¿Cómo llegó la voz *chaleco* a tomar semejante acepción?

Comment: [Referencia obligada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ast%C3%A9rix_el_Galo).

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de la narrativa criminal del S.XIX de México, encontré un personaje que le llamaban "Chalequero", y que se dedicaba a violar mujeres, apodo dado por "Chaleco" ya que en México la palabra "chaleco" significa en el lenguaje informal " *a la fuerza*" y cuyo apodo servía para asustar a las prostitutas.

No obstante continué investigando ya que ello por si solo, aunque podría ser una posibilidad, no me convencía hasta que di con algo más interesante.

Al principio histórico de la **La chupa** esta era una prenda de indumentaria masculina que se extendió por Europa en el S. XVIII y que formaba parte del *traje a la francesa*. Esta Chupa antigua, era parte del vestido que cubría el tronco del cuerpo. Con el tiempo la prenda se reduce notablemente, *los bordes inferiores se cierran en pico, se eliminan las mangas y se añaden solapas*, dando lugar al actual "**Chaleco**".

Por otra parte tenemos otro conjunto de palabras que conectan con esta "Chupa - Chaleco" y que tienen otros significados. Así tenemos ya;

- Chupa llamada Chaleco
- Chupita es el diminutivo de "Chupa", por tanto diminutivo de Chaleco, Chalequito.
- Chupín forma en la que era llamado al Chaleco, también recibía el nombre de Chupetín.
- Chupón Persona que se dedica a sacar el dinero a otro con astucia.
- Y por último y el más interesante; **Chupona** - como mujer de mal vivir.

Digamos que esta familia de palabras conectadas **Chupa como Chaleco, Chupín, Chupita, Chupona...**son las que le dieron a la palabra "**Chaleco**" el sentido que aún se lee de mujer despreciable, de mal vivir, etc. Las voz no solo la he encontrado en Andalucía sino en sitios más alejados como Aragón, con la acepción de « prostituta » o « mujer de vida alegre ». María Moliner la recoge como ( DUE , II , p . ... querida » ; tal ( por cual ), persona despreciable, tuna, pilla.

P.D Quizás en Sevilla el "Chaleco", como palabra, jersey de pico, suéter de manga larga, recuerde aquellas primeras "Chupas", que luego se acortaron y recibieron el nombre de "Chaleco", siendo la Chupa ó Chaleco, la reminiscencia nominal de aquella pieza ajustada y de manga larga.